# Add a unique ID to Drupal Views list groupings

Tags: php, drupal, view, grouping

I'm using Views 3 in Drupal 7 to output a list of fields and using a grouping field to generate separate lists. I need each of the groupings to have a unique ID attribute applied to the < ul > but they don't by default.

As far as I'm aware I would need to edit the [views-view-list.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-list.tpl.php/7) template but I don't know how to achieve a unique ID per iteration.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way I can think of off the top of my head...

```
<?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <ul id="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

that would go in your views-view-list.tpl.php file.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Jonathan, however I should have been more specific by saying that the unique ID is to be used by jQuery and therefore needs to be consistent. 'uniqid();' seemingly produces a random string with every page load so unfortunately can't be used in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
Put a div around everyting in view-views-list.tpl.php. You can (ab-)use the $title to generate unique (but consistent) id's.

Do it like this:

```
<?php $id = str_replace('FOR ALL UNWANTED CHARS','',$title); ?>

<div id="<?php print strtolower($id); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $view->dom_id variable. It is a unique id for that views instance.

In your .tpl.php file:

```
<?php print $view->dom_id; ?>
```

From comments in modules\views\theme\theme.inc:

```
<?php
    // It is true that the DIV wrapper has classes denoting the name of the view
    // and its display ID, but this is not enough to unequivocally match a view
    // with its HTML, because one view may appear several times on the page. So
    // we set up a hash with the current time, $dom_id, to issue a "unique" identifier for
    // each view. This identifier is written to both Drupal.settings and the DIV
    // wrapper.
?>
```